# Invalid Code of Conduct anchor links in the comment flagging dialog

Tags: bug, status-review, comment-flags, flag-dialog

When I click the flag icon to flag a comment, a dialog box opens with four options. The first two contain links to the Code of Conduct:

> - It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
>   This comment attacks a person or group. Learn more in our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#personal-attacks).
> - It's unfriendly or unkind.
>   This comment is rude or condescending. Learn more in our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language).

The URLs are:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#personal-attacks`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language`

However, clicking those links takes me to the top of the Code of Conduct page, since those anchors don't seem to exist on that page.

Some anchors that do exist are: `expectations`, `unacceptable-behavior` and `reporting`.

I suggest that the links in the dialog box be updated — the first one to `unacceptable-behavior`, and the second to `expectations`, perhaps?